# Dynamic Function Watcher in JS

Tags: javascript, function, wrapper

I'm working on a pet project, a little front-end library for students. It reads variables/code in a JS file and tests it, outputting some panels. The code itself roughly follows the Jest framework.

My problem is that I'm trying to create a function that watches the execution of other functions, counts them, and lets me access the count.

```
function watchFunction(funcName){
    let originalFunction = window[funcName];
    let counter = 0;
    
    // Wrap the function, counts when called
    window[funcName] = function(...args){
        console.log("watching");
        counter++;
        return originalFunction(...args);
    }

    return {
        getCount: () => {return counter},
        reset: () => {
            // Unwrap the function
            window[funcName] = originalFunction
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work for methods like `Number()` or `parseInt()`, but I don't know how I would go about accessing methods like `Math.floor()`, or prototype methods like `Array.prototype.map()`.

I've tried passing in the function reference instead of using `window["funcNameString"]`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have suggestions or tips for wrapping functions or watching functions like this?

EDIT:

It appears a solution was found!

```
function watchFunction(obj, fName) {
  let counter = 0;

  const originalFunction = obj[fName];
  obj[fName] = (...args) => {
    counter++;
    return originalFunction.bind(obj)(...args);
  };

  return {
    removeWatcher: () => (obj[fName] = originalFunction),
    resetCount: () => (counter = 0),
    getCount: () => counter,
  };
}
```

Example of use:

```
// Array.prototype.push
const arrayPushWatcher = watchFunction(Array.prototype, "push");
let arr = [];

// 0
console.log("Array.prototype.push", arrayPushWatcher.getCount());
arr.push(1);

// 1
console.log("Array.prototype.push", arrayPushWatcher.getCount());
arr.push(1);

// 2
console.log("Array.prototype.push", arrayPushWatcher.getCount());
arrayPushWatcher.removeWatcher();
arr.push(1);

// 2 (stopped counting)
console.log("Array.prototype.push", arrayPushWatcher.getCount());
```

Comment: Can you share the context of how this function is called and how it gets the functions it is watching?

Comment: That's a more complicated question... I'm building a little front-end library that can run tests on student code to check that variables are set, functions return the right values, and with the solution above... can watch to make sure students use certain functions when solving problems. To explain it fully would take awhile, but here's the idea:  

expect(sortValues).withArgs(["c", "b", "a"]).toUseFunction(Array.prototype, "sort")

Comment: It can be written concisely using native Proxy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to watch for any function call

---

Is that what you want? I can also write a block for this function so that it determines whether an object has been passed in or a string. If string -> run this function on window as a property "objectThatStoresFunction".

I've tried playing around with the `Function.prototype`, but it doesn't really work. So the function turned out a bit more complex.

This code below works both with functions / objects on window Array.prototype.map (Prototype / Class functions)

```js
function watchFunction(objectThatStoresFunction, functionName) {
  let counter = 0;

  const originalFunction = objectThatStoresFunction[functionName];

  objectThatStoresFunction[functionName] = (...args) => {
    counter += 1;
    return originalFunction(...args);
  }

  return {
    getCount: () => {
      return counter
    }
  }
}
const mathRoundWatcher = watchFunction(Math, 'round');
// 0
console.log(mathRoundWatcher.getCount());
// 1
Math.round(99666.9999999);
console.log(mathRoundWatcher.getCount());
// 2
Math.round(999999999.99);
console.log(mathRoundWatcher.getCount());
```

```js
function watchFunction(objectThatStoresFunction, functionName, optionalOriginalFunction) {
const self = this;
  if (optionalOriginalFunction) {
    objectThatStoresFunction = this.window;
    functionName = optionalOriginalFunction.name;
  }
  let counter = 0;

  const originalFunction = objectThatStoresFunction[functionName] || optionalOriginalFunction;
  objectThatStoresFunction[functionName] = (...args) => {
    counter += 1;
    return originalFunction.bind(self)(...args);
  }
  return {
    // should it remove the watcher or reset the count?
    reset: () => objectThatStoresFunction[functionName] = originalFunction,
    getCount: () => {
return counter;
    }
  }
}
const arrayMapWatcher = watchFunction(Array.prototype, 'map');

// 0
console.log('Array.prototype.map', arrayMapWatcher.getCount());

[-99].map(() => {});

// 1
console.log('Array.prototype.map', arrayMapWatcher.getCount());

const mathRoundWatcher = watchFunction(Math, 'round');

// 0
console.log('Math.round', mathRoundWatcher.getCount());

// 1
Math.round(99666.9999999);
console.log('Math.round', mathRoundWatcher.getCount());
// 2
Math.round(999999999.99);
console.log('Math.round', mathRoundWatcher.getCount());
const alertWatcher = watchFunction(null, null, window.alert);
// 0
console.log('window.alert', alertWatcher.getCount());
// 1
window.alert('1');
console.log('window.alert', alertWatcher.getCount());
// 2
alert('2')
console.log('window.alert', alertWatcher.getCount());
// reset the alertWatcher counter
alertWatcher.reset();
```

This code above breaks the stacksnippets.com when used with Array.prototype.map for some reason, please see this JsFiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/ctbjnawz/3/

Comment: Oh that's clever. I'll give this a try soon to see if it hits all my test cases!

Comment: So this *mostly* works. My goals are to be able to watch functions like:

parseInt      Math.random       Array.prototype.map

This solution works for the first two, as they are methods of objects. Array.map has some difficulty since it's a class method. This seems to not be a solution for that type of function. I'll keep tinkering with it.

Comment: I'll think how this can be fixed, will edit the answer and let you know if I find a solution

Comment: This updated code in the snippet №2 works with listening to Array.prototype.map's calls too

Comment: It worked in your test cases! I tried trimming down the code and it appears to be working for my use cases. So far: window.parseInt, Math.round, Array.prototype.map, Array.prototype.push, Array.prototype.filter ... bind() was the secret! thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean a method of an instance or object?  One way is to create a new function. e.g

```
function WatchInstanceMethods(instance, functionName){
let originalFunction = window[instance][funcName];
let counter = 0;
   window[instance][functionName] = function(...args){
        console.log("watching");
        counter++;
        return originalFunction(...args);
    }
     return {
        getCount: () => {return counter},
        reset: () => {
            // Unwrap the function
            window[funcName] = originalFunction
        }
    }

}
```

although adding support for chaining methods will get difficult with more nested methods but you can pass a string for functionName name and split it to have each layer of calling instance for function and repeat the logic above.

Comment: I think this might also be a reasonable solution, I'll test it shortly and see if it fits my situation.

Honestly I think that going just 3 levels deep is probably enough. That would cover String(), Math.round(), and Array.prototype.map(). Which is just about everything I would want to cover.

Comment: This one also works for the two test cases parseInt and Math.random. My current troubles is trying to wrap class methods like Array.map. Any ideas?

Comment: But window.Math.round is undefined because Math doesn't exist on window. This would probably only work with alert, not even console.log